# Custom Discussion board alerts stopped working in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, alert

We had Custom Discussion board alerts on 4 servers SharePoint 2013 farm working until I changed something in the `AlertHandler : IAlertNotifyHandler` class
I tried debugging by attaching to the timer service but nothing works.

Anyone has a way to debug or figure out why there are no alert emails from Discussion boards but there are from other lists. (Even twice).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the farm had an invalid server registered with it.
After removing the server from the farm, custom alerts started showing up in the inbox.